# Discord.js Error - MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

Every time I try to make more than 10 commands I get the error:

```
node MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message listeners added to [Client]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I tried fixing it by doing `emitter.setMaxListeners()` and it didn't fix it so I searched online and tried to fix it by using `process.setMaxListeners(0);` but that didn't work either. If there is a fix for this please let me know, and if you want to see what code I have written for my bot please let me know which part of the code you would like to see.

Comment: Does your code have a lot of `client.on('message', message => ...` events?

Comment: @PerplexingParadox  i use client everytime i have to make a new command because of my command handler so like ```callback: async (message, args, text, client) => {```

Comment: Consider using `client.destroy()` at the end of your script once you're done then. Link: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=destroy

Comment: @PerplexingParadox whenever i run a command now the bot logs out and i cant use it anymore, could there be anyway to fix this?

Comment: What does your command handler code look like? It works fine when I tried it.

Comment: @PerplexingParadox
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_ejJoFbKR6LexklIArqi_-Hu6bmBlppSl-GZgBNvwoY/edit?usp=sharing
since it was too big
and also the code you use when making a command is

```module.exports = {
    commands: '',//command name(s)
    minArgs: ,//minimum argumnets
    maxArgs: ,//maximum arguments
    callback: async (message, args, text, client) => {
},
    permissions: [],//permissions
    requiredRoles: [],//required roles
  }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.setMaxListeners(0);
```

it's not emitter or process you are doing it to, it's the client. Oh and I am pretty sure you need it at the top of your code, before your commands

Comment: Although this shuts the error up, it doesn't fix the issue. I *highly* doubt there's a good reason for adding a new event listener every single command. Soon enough, all the listeners will pile up and your bot will run out of memory.

Comment: Like @Lioness100, this is not a good solution. It is much more recommended to have one event listener handling all commands.